# Flutter-web TextFormField issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

usually I can disable/grey-out a button until a TextFormField meets certain parameters in flutter by something like this:

```
TextFormField(
controller: _controller
value: (value)
)

SubmitButton(
onPressed: _controller.text.isNotEmpty ? _submit : null;
)
```

But when compiled as a website the Button seems no longer aware of the controller value...

I have tried targeting in several different ways, e.g. _controller.value.text.isEmpty and _controller.text.isEmpty...

I'm guessing I'm missing something or this method just isn't possible for web ... Is there any other way to get the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, your code shouldn't work in `flutter mobile` either, but may be works because of screen keyboard causes widget rebuild when showing or hiding.
To fix this issue we have to use stateful widget with state variable like `canSubmit` and update it in textField's listener `onChange` with `setState` method. Then every time the text changes, our stateful widget will update the submit button..

```dart
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  bool canSubmit;

  @override
  void initState() {
    canSubmit = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  canSubmit = value.isNotEmpty;
                });
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: canSubmit ? _submit : null,
              child: Text('Submit'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submit() {
    print('Submitted');
  }
}
```

Comment: Ooops! Awesome- thanks for the reply. Will update now :D